# ValueError: unconverted data remains: 72

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to change the object of the first column into Datatime format. The data looks like this.

23.08.1972   798   800   795    800

If tried this function

```
df.loc[:, "Datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Datum, format = "%d.%m.%y" )
```

where "Datum" is the first column.

But now it shows me this error: "ValueError: unconverted data remains: 72"
There is no way for me to look through all the rows by hand. How can i see the uncovered data and have a look at it or solve the problem right away?

Comment: check the rows by `bad_dates= df['Datum'][pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'], format = "%d.%m.%y" ,errors='coerce').isna()]` if you want to ignore the rows with bad dates: `pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'], format = "%d.%m.%y" ,errors='coerce')`, we don't know which one you want

Answer (score 0):

use one extra argument error = 'coerce' it'll convert the value to NaN if the format is wrong -

```
df.loc[:, "Datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Datum, format = "%d.%m.%y" ,errors= 'coerce')
```

Then check for NAN values in that particular column.